# ModSecurity: Ignore Array ARGS

Tags: owasp, mod-security

I want an exclusion rule for a request to be evaluated at runtime. The body of the request is an array. e.g

```
["somestring", "someRandomString",....]
```

This is the rule I have written:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /my/url" \

              "phase:2,nolog,pass,id:10000,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942100;ARGS"
```

However, the array ARGS are not excluded. I have not found anything about this in the online docs. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this rule defined before 942100 in your config? Rules with the action ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942100 actions must be specified *before* the rules they alter, unlike SecRuleUpdateTargetById which must be specified *after* confusingly enough.

Comment: @BarryPollard I defined it after. Let me check. Also I was thinking the syntax might be off. So it seems the syntax is correct?

Comment: Yup syntax looks fine. Define it before and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this is defined before rule 942100.

`ctl` actions must be specified **before** the rules they alter, unlike SecRuleUpdateTargetById which must be specified **after**, confusingly enough.

Comment: We are revamping our config to allow this; will get back to you when done.